# Law of Iterated Expectations and functional forms of the conditional mean functions

Tags: statistics

Let $y$ be a random variable such that $E[y|z]=z'\beta$. What can be said about
$E[y|z,x]$ ?
Using the law of iterated expectations, we can check that an admissible form for $E[y|z,x]$ is given by
$$
E[y|z,x] = \phi_0(x) + \phi_1(x)z'\beta, 
$$
for any functions $\phi_0, \phi_1$ such that $E[\phi_0(x)|z]=0, E[\phi_1(x)|z]=1.$
Is there a necessary and sufficient condition for the functional form $E[y|z,x]$ when $E[y|z]=z'\beta$ ? References on related topics are welcome.

Comment: If this form is actually true, you need $E[\phi_0(x)\mid z]=0,E[\phi_1(x)\mid z]=1$.

Comment: Yes indeed, there was a typo there, thank you.